# Can I make my cellphone a 3.5mm jack bluetooth transceiver?

Tags: bluetooth, transceiver, headphones

I want to hear sound from my TV using my [Beats Solo3 wireless headphones](https://www.beatsbydre.com/headphones/solo3-wireless) the problem is that the TV doesn't have a bluetooth transmitter (or any wireless connectivity) it has USB and 3.5mm headphone jack exits (among others).

I've tried to connect my cellphone and my TV using  [3.5mm Male2Male jacks cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#General_use) and BT connect my cellphone to the headphones, but I didn't hear no sound.

Can a cellphone **receive audio signals** with it's 3.5mm jack (essentially becoming headphones) using a 3rd party software or electronically that's impossible ?

Thank you

Comment: Read this https://www.reddit.com/r/diyelectronics/comments/7t3t29/using_an_old_smartphone_as_a_bluetooth_audio/ And/or buy a BT transmitter for couple of dollars.

Comment: "I didn't hear no sound" is equivalent logically to "I did hear sound". Just saying.

Comment: This is indeed possible, but it's a question about *usage* of a consumer product and software.  If it is a design question at all, it would be a mobile phone *app* design one, which is not on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you want cannot be done, at least not in such a simple way.

You could use a cable that converts the TV's signal to a signal that the microphone input of your phone could use. But then you'd still need some software to take that signal and make a Bluetooth stream from it. And even if you managed that it would be a mono (not stereo) signal as the microphone inputs on phones are generally mono only.

Recommending devices is off-topic actually but I'll humor you since I know exactly what you need:

What you can do is buy the same device which I bought recently:

[image]

Here's an [ebay link](https://www.ebay.com/p/Wireless-Bluetooth-Transmitter-Stereo-Audio-Music-Adapter-for-TV-Phone-PC-Dongle/23021392924)

This can be powered from a USB charger and converts 3.5mm jack analog audio to a bluetooth stream.

Comment: Your claim here that the jack is output only is not correct - the 3.5mm jack would include a *mono* microphone *input* for a headset mic.  A little attenuation on the electrical side (you can buy that in connectorized form) software to sample it and send the audio as BT audio and it could work, though it's likely to have annoying latency.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sure, nitpicking but you're right. What I mean was that it will not work in the way OP intends it to work.

Comment: Actually it *will* work in the way the OP intends.  They just need an audio *input* cable and the right software.

Comment: Sure, **if** you'd have the right cable and **if** he'd have the right software. I prefer to "see through" the question, get out of "engineering mode" and suggest a more practical solution. But feel free to also write an answer suggesting your solution.